# Google coral Mendel Linux Authentication Error

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, embedded-linux, mendel-os

I am trying to compile Mendel Linux on Ubuntu 20.04 as per:

https://coral.googlesource.com/docs/+/refs/heads/master/GettingStarted.md

I receive the following:

`WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated! libedgetpu1-std python3-tflite-runtime python3-pycoral E: There were unauthenticated packages and -y was used without --allow-unauthenticated make: *** [/rootdir/build/rootfs.mk:150: /rootdir/out/target/product/imx8m_phanbell/obj/ROOTFS/rootfs_arm64.patched.img] Error 100 I am doing this on an Ubuntu 20.04 system.`

I tried installing the three packages as per:

https://coral.ai/software/#debian-packages

I also tried :

`$ sudo apt-key update
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get upgrade

$sudo -i #to change the user to root

$ apt-get update --allow-unauthenticated

$ apt-get update --allow-insecure-repositories
`
but I still get the above warning and error.

Please if you know how I could solve this problem to finish my build it would be much appreciated, thank you.